# How to do this Math induction problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Show that:

$$\frac n3 + \frac n9 + \frac {n}{27} + \cdots = \frac n2.$$

When I start with $\frac 13 + \frac 19 + \frac {1}{27}$ it leads to a number close to $.5$ but it's not exactly $.5$.

Comment: Do you expect to get exactly $0.5$? The LHS is an infinite sum...

Comment: $\frac{n}{3} = \frac{n}{2} - ?$, then $\frac{n}{3} + \frac{n}{9} = \frac{n}{2} - ??$, $\frac{n}{3} + \frac{n}{9} + \frac{n}{27} = \frac{n}{2} - ???$

Answer (score 3):

This is not (necessarily) an induction problem. Rather, it is a problem of real analysis, involving [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). It is a fact that for real $r$ with $-1<r<1,$ we have $$r^0+r^1+r^2+r^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-r},$$ and so $$r^1+r^2+r^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-r}-1.$$ In particular, for $r=\frac13,$ this becomes $$\frac13+\frac19+\frac1{27}+\cdots=\cfrac1{1-\frac13}-1=\cfrac1{\frac23}-1=\frac32-1=\frac12,$$ and so $$\frac{n}3+\frac{n}9+\frac{n}{27}+\cdots=n\cdot\left(\frac13+\frac19+\frac1{27}+\cdots\right)=n\cdot\frac12=\frac{n}2.$$

---

As an alternate approach, using sequences, you could let $a_1=\frac{n}3$ and $a_{k+1}=a_k+\frac{n}{3^{k+1}}$ for $k\ge 1$. Then you can show by induction (using the recursive definition) that $$\frac{n}2-a_k=\frac{n}{3^k\cdot 2}$$ for all $k.$ Hence, for large enough $k,$ we can make $\frac{n}2-a_k$ as small as we like, meaning $a_k\to \frac{n}2,$ or put another way, $$\frac{n}3+\frac{n}9+\frac{n}{27}+\cdots=\frac{n}2.$$

Comment: Eh, it could be an induction problem: produce an explicit error term $e_n$ and induct on the statement "the finite sum is between $\frac12$ and $\frac12-e_n$." You'd still need limits to talk about infinite sums in detail, but if $e_n$ was obviously going to zero I'd probably call it a proof.

Comment: I think it is obvious from the way the question is written that the person asking doesn't know the difference between a finite and infinite sum.

Comment: @Eric: That occurred to me, too. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: where can I find more about real analysis? Sorry I'm really new to this stuff. And how did you derive a/1-r ?

Comment: The idea is this: Take any real $r$. I claim that for non-positive integers $k,$ we have $$1-r^{k+1}=(1-r)(1+r+\cdots+r^k).\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ This is easily checked for small $k$. (When $k=1,$ we're just applying the difference of squares formula.) For larger $k$, we can note that $$\begin{align}1-r^{k+1} &= 1-r+r-r^2+\cdots+r^{k-1}-r^k+r^k-r^{k+1}\\ &= (1-r)\cdot 1+(1-r)\cdot r+\cdots+(1-r)\cdot r^{k-1}+(1-r)\cdot r^k\\ &= (1-r)(1+r+\cdots+r^{k-1}+r^k).\end{align}$$ When $-1<r<1,$ the left-hand side of $(\heartsuit)$ can be made as close to $1$ as we like by making $k$ large enough. (cont)

Comment: (inued) What we say, then, is that for $-1<r<1,$ we have $$1=(1-r)(1+r+r^2+\cdots),$$ so $$1+r+r^2+\cdots=\frac1{1-r},$$ and so for any $a$ we have $$a+ar+ar^2+\cdots=\frac{a}{1-r}.$$ Does this make sense to you? As for where to find out more about real analysis, I recommend that you take a course in it. If you're looking for recommendations of reference materials for self-study, you probably would be better served to ask that as a separate question, with the tag `(reference-request)` appended.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the above answers uses induction, and therefore neither is responsive to the question.  Hint to the OP:  Try an induction hypothesis of the form

> The sum of the first $k$ terms is 1/2-f(k)

where $f(k)$ is some function that clearly goes to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\frac n3 + \frac n9 + \frac n{27}+\dots=n\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac 1{3^n}$.  Using the terminology in the linked article, we have $a=\frac 13$ (the first term) and $r=\frac 13$ (the ratio between successive terms.  As long as $|r| \lt 1$ this infinite sum will converge to $\frac a{1-r}=\frac {\frac 13}{1-\frac 13}=\frac 12$